# Why is my Node Express Mongoose app making get requests to these sites?

Tags: express, ubuntu, cloud9

I am running a Node (v 8.11.2), Express (with express-generator) and Mongoose app on a Ubuntu 16.04 server.  I access it using AWS Cloud 9 service.

In the console.log messages I see that my app is making GET requests to these sites which are of zero interest to my code.  What or why is making these requests?

```
GET http://www.baidu.com/?rands=_1989643718421222425724576 200 0.748 ms - 207
GET http://www.so.com/?rands=_144682544013674723168320 200 0.874 ms - 207
GET http://www.baidu.com/?rands=_860019281611321521293372 200 1.006 ms - 207
GET http://www.search.com/?rands=_14658606404382821623860 200 0.749 ms - 207
GET http://www.so.com/?rands=_579087861617667724519440 200 0.783 ms - 207
GET http://azenv.net/ 200 1.505 ms - 207
GET http://www.ip138.com/ 200 1.403 ms - 207
GET http://boxun.com/ 200 0.999 ms - 207
GET http://www.wujieliulan.com/ - - ms - -
GET http://www.123cha.com/ 200 0.744 ms - 207
GET http://www.epochtimes.com/ - - ms - -
GET http://www.minghui.org/ - - ms - -
GET http://www.ip.cn/ 200 1.078 ms - 207
GET http://www.search.com/?rands=_298542756025728303317028 200 0.806 ms - 207
GET http://www.rfa.org/english/ 404 2.094 ms - 1754
```

Comment: Zero way to help with the information provided.

Comment: @Dave Newton I am not sure how to begin understanding what's going on?  What info should be collected?

Comment: I have deployed this basic demo app, which doesn't call these sites.  https://www.djamware.com/post/58b27ce080aca72c54645983/how-to-create-nodejs-expressjs-and-mongodb-crud-web-application.  Is it cloud 9 that's calling these sites?

Comment: From your server? Makes no sense-but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: Yes, cloud 9 can be installed and run from your own server.

Comment: ... I was asking for confirmation that the are outbound requests from your server code to the external sites you list.

Comment: Yes, they are.  They are on the console log of my node process running this demo app.

Comment: Okay, so you'll have to check (a) the demo app and (b) the modules used by the demo app. We have absolutely nothing to go on--it's unclear what kind of assistance you expect at this point.

Comment: I have been running the app outside of cloud 9 and there's no such behavior.  I'm going to run c9 without my digitalocean ubuntu server to see if I can isolate the behavior.  Maybe my DO server has been hacked.