# Why is my Node Express app making these GET requests?

Tags: node.js, express, networking, router

I'm running a Node Express (4.16.4) site off of an old Mac Mini, and I just saw it make a few questionable requests to some Chinese news websites. These same requests, as well as a similar problem has only been brought up in one other question I could find (which has yet to be answered.)

[Why is my Node Express Mongoose app making get requests to these sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765338/why-is-my-node-express-mongoose-app-making-get-requests-to-these-sites)

```
GET /manager/html 404 264.190 ms - 191 (Router Management page.)
GET http://www.123cha.com 200 85.242 ms - 2889
GET http://api.ipify.org/ 200 49.589 ms - 2889
GET http://www.epochtimes.com/ 200 44.209 ms - 2889

GET http://www.ip.cn/ 200 26.324 ms - 2889
GET http://www.wujieliulan.com/ - - ms - -
GET http://www.minghui.org/ - - ms - -
GET http://www.123cha.com/ 200 58.645 ms - 2889
GET http://www.rfa.org/english/ - - ms - -
GET http://boxun.com/ - - ms - -
```

Packages:

```
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"body-parser": "^1.18.3",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"emoji-strip": ">=0.0.1",
"emoji-tree": ">=0.0.1",
"express": "^4.16.4",
"jade": "^1.11.0",
"jsonfile": ">=0.0.1",
"log-update": "^2.3.0",
"minimist": ">=0.0.1",
"moment": ">=0.0.1",
"morgan": "^1.9.1",
"mysql": ">=0.0.1",
"node-async-loop": ">=0.0.1",
"node-cleanup": "^2.1.2",
"node-ipc": ">=0.0.1",
"nodemon": "^1.18.6",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"sentiment": "^5.0.1",
"serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
"stylus": "^0.54.5",
"twitter": ">=0.0.1"
```

I have port 8080 open for the site, and 22 for SSH. I am updating the IP through [DuckDns](https://www.duckdns.org/).

Should I be worried about this? Is a package compromised, or DuckDns? Am I compromising my entire network by running this?

If you need any additional info, please let me know. I'm new to networking, so I might not have provided some essential piece of the puzzle.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the modules you installed in your app (from `package.json`). It seems like you're accessing your router management page, which is serving you these adds.

Comment: Edited the post to include packages. I wasn't accessing the router management page while it was making these calls, so I assume someone else was.

Comment: Just out of  curiosity, if you navigate to your router page, does it server any ads or anything suspicious? This is weird stuff indeed, I'm as intrigued as you are. It could be DuckDns but I'm not sure how can it even pull this off, being just a dyn dns.

Comment: No, nothing of the sort. A very bare-bones login page is served.
https://imgur.com/lgMVdt8

Comment: The calls to api.ipify.com and ip.cn worry me. Might be an automated program that connects to "X" IP, reads, possibly logs the IP through ipify or ip.cn, and has the server GET these websites to... boost views? None of them seem terribly malicious but, then again, I can't read Chinese.